# Centering text block within Bootstrap's carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center a block of text (not each line of text) within a Bootstrap carousel item.  If I use a div within a carousel item and specify the classes "container" and "center-block", the block of text shifts right a bit, but isn't centered horizontally.  I was hoping to avoid using fixed margins to center the text.  Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="container center-block"> 
                <h3>List</h3>
                <ol>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                </ol>
                <p> this is a test of a longer string</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use the bootstrap carousel caption ?

Comment: @shin - caption will center each line of text, not the block.  Also, I want the block of text as the main body of the screen, not located near the bottom.